# Database Script Issue

Tags: magento2, install-script

I have used the below script for my database creation in magento2. The file location is `app\code\Ingram\Webshop\sql\webshop_setup\mysql4-install-1.0.0.php`

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->run(“
CREATE TABLE `reseller_authentication` ( `r_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `App_id` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , `Reseller_id` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , `Secret_key` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , `created_time` DATETIME NOT NULL , `update_time` DATETIME NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`r_id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
“);
$installer->endSetup();
```

and my config.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../Store/etc/config.xsd">
     <default>
        <webshop>
            <module>
                <is_enabled>1.0.0</is_enabled>
            </module>
        </webshop>
    </default>
    <global>
        <models>
            <Webshop>
                <class>Ingram_Webshop_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>Webshop_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </Webshop>
            <Webshop_mysql4>
                <class>Ingram_Webshop_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <Webshop>
                        <table>Webshop_Reseller_Authentication</table>
                    </Webshop>
                </entities>
            </Webshop_mysql4>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Then i have run the command `php bin\magento setup:upgrade` in command prompt. But I not getting table created at the magento database. I would be really helpful if anybody giving suggestion on this!

Comment: You are trying to use M1 code in M2. That won't work.

Answer (score 0):

As  @Marius said, You are trying to use Magento 1 code in Magento 2

I have added some resources links for creating custom model/table creation.

http://webkul.com/blog/how-to-create-a-new-database-table-in-magento-2-0/

http://www.mage-world.com/blog/create-a-module-with-custom-database-table-in-magento-2.html

You can follow the resources to create a schema/model script in magento 2.